# Alternative argument to show that function diverges everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

Consider the function:

$$f(x) = x^{\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}} +\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}} - \frac{1}{4}x^{-\frac{3}{2}} +\frac{1}{15}x^{\frac{5}{2}} + \cdots$$

which is constructed such that $f$ is (or at least looks like) a solution to $f' = f$.

Then, $f(x) = Ae^x$ for some constant $A$. But $f$ diverges at $x=0$, so "$A=\pm\infty$" and $f$ diverges everywhere.

I appreciate that this is hardly rigorous, and that a rigorous proof could be given through analytical methods. But is the concept of the argument flawed in any way, and could it be made rigorous?

Comment: Why does it look like $f'=f$? For example the derivative of $\frac25x^{5/2}$ is $x^{3/2}$ not $\frac23x^{3/2}$

Comment: @Henry Thanks; I will correct this. But considering I said that this is by construction, I am sure you understood what I meant and could have pointed this out another way.

Comment: Your definition of $f$ seems circular to me and not well-defined (the problem lies behind the ellipsis). When we write an infinite series by writing the first few terms followed by an ellipsis (like $a_1+a_2+a_3+\ldots$), it is basically a shorthand for the formal limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$; it is quite evident that your general term isn't well-defined.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Why couldn't, for instance, the general term be $a_k x^\frac{2k-1}{2} + b_k x^{-\frac{2k-1}{2}}$, where $a_k, b_k$ are the appropriate coefficients given the "boundary condition" $a_1 = 1$? If you want to split up each term by exponent and find the coefficients in closed form, I am certain with some effort you could do that too. Although I was not careful about constructing this series (for the purposes of this question), I am not convinced that it cannot be expressed with a general term.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Because the general term in your comment above is a sum of two terms, one with a positive and the other with a negative exponent, it will not even be *defined* when $x=0.$ But the general solution to $f'(x)=f(x)$ is defined at any real $x.$

Comment: @legionwhale The general term could not be a sum of two monomials because then the formal series of that general term would not be equal to the sum you wrote. In order for your series to be expressed with a general term, you need to have a general term $c_kx^{r_k},$ and have that $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^nc_kx^{r_k}.$

Comment: @coffeemath I believe you meant to reply to me. It is true that it is not defined at $x=0$, but I did not specify the domain, so take it to be the reals without 0. You are incorrect that this is defined everywhere; it clearly diverges at for example $x=1$.

Comment: @legionwhale Also, you have still not described in what way your series appears to satisfy $f'=f.$

Comment: @legionwhale No, you are wrong. The general solutions of the equation $f'=f$ are defined everywhere, including at $x=1.$ This is what coffeemath stated. They made it clear that your function is not defined at $x=0,$ but they never claimed it is defined everywhere. You are misreading here.

Comment: @Angel Thank you. By general solution, I mistakenly thought he was referring to the solution in my question. Are there any other conditions on a formal series? I am currently not seeing why this cannot be expressed as a formal series. I will work on writing up my supposed formal series in an edit to the answer.

Comment: @legionwhale Yes I misadressed my comment. But what I was claiming to be defined everywhere is the general solution to $f'=f.$ [*not* the proposed strange series.]

Comment: @legionwhale The argument is not that your construction cannot be expressed as a formal series. The argument is that your construction is not a formal series, and so as a mathematical object, it is meaningless. It is not a well-defined mathematical object that we can study. It is not "anything," so to speak. You need to give us a formal series, because what you gave is not. That is the what the objection is.

Comment: @coffeemath I understand, thank you.

Comment: @Angel I understand. However, I do not see why it is not clear which formal series I am referring to. Given that the coefficient of $x^\frac{1}{2}$ is 1, all of the other coefficients can be found. Let the general nth term be the mononomial term with exponent $r_n$ where $r_n$ is the sequence $\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}, -\frac{3}{2} ...$. Is this not what the first few terms I wrote suggest?

Comment: @legionwhale The reason it is unclear which formal series you are referring to is because you claim the series definitely satisfies $f'=f.$ However, if the sequence being summed is the sequence you say it is, then this is not true. Also, it is unclear to me that the coefficients can indeed be found just by knowing that the $0$th coefficient is $1.$ You have not provided us a recursion that the coefficients satisfy.

Comment: @Angel The coefficients are found to fit s.t. the derivative is a term in $f$. For instance, $x^\frac{3}{2}$ has coefficient $\frac{2}{3}$ so that its derivative is exactly the term $x^\frac{1}{2}$. I think I see your objection now. Are you saying that the term-by-term derivative of the formal series must produce exactly the same formal series as you began with, without any reordering of the terms?

Comment: @legionwhale Yes. You cannot arbitrarily reorder terms in a series without changing what the series actually converges to, in general, and when derivatives comes into the mix, this becomes especially problematic.

Comment: @Angel Thank you. I know little about this (as may be clear!). Is there a sense of absolute convergence for formal series (and/or formal power series), wherein terms can be rearranged without affecting the limit? Is it uniform convergence?

Comment: @Angel One last question. Let $s_n$ be the partial sum for the original series; $t_n$ for the series after term-wise differentiation. Then, every term in $s_n$ is a term in $t_{n+2}$ and every term in $t_{n+2}$ is a term in $s_{n+4}$ (by construction). I have forgotten my analysis a little bit, but is this not sufficient to say that they tend to the same limit?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly,
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4^n n!}{(2n+1)!}x^{(2n+1)/2}
+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n-1)!}{4^n (n-1)!}x^{-(2n+1)/2}
$$
The first term converges when $0<x$ while the radius of convergence of the second term is $R=0$.

Hence the function is nowhere definable!

Comment: Even $R=0$ does not work with the second term since you cannot have $0^{-1/2}$ (and you are missing $(-1)^n$ though it hardly matters), while the first term does converge when $x=0$

Comment: Dear Yiorgos, this does not answer the question. I did not ask for the radius of convergence, but rather an assessment of the conceptual argument I offered. Your argument is fine. But I could have easily produced it myself if that's what I wanted. This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you extend the negative exponents, the typical term is something like $$(-1)^k x^{-k-\frac12} \dfrac{(2k)!}{k!2^{2k+1}}$$ and for any $x>0$ that term will eventually start growing in magnitude as $k$ increases, while it is not defined or not real for $x \le 0$

Comment: Thank you, but this does not answer the question. I agree that the function diverges everywhere. It is a fair observation that the function is not defined at $x \le 0$, but equally I never specified the domain. Let's restrict to the strictly positive reals. My question is asking whether or not my argument, in concept, is valid. I am not trying to find out whether or not the function is well-defined or not; I have already stated that it isn't.

Comment: @legionwhale That does not make any sense. A series cannot converge on only $x\geq0.$

Comment: @Angel From Wikipedia: "a formal series is an infinite sum that is considered independently from any notion of convergence". I am finding your objections astonishingly unclear.

Comment: @legionwhale But we are not dealing with a formal series. We are dealing with an asymptotic expansion. Asymptotic expansions can be constructed from formal series, but they are not the same thing. We are dealing with functions here, and with differential equations. Formal series do not play a major role here. The problem is that the function in your post is ill-defined, so we ask you that you properly define the formal series, so that then we can talk about the properties of the corresponding series-function. But convergence in $x\geq0$ and divergence elsewhere is not one possible property.

Comment: @Angel You have been referred to formal series multiple times in your replies to me, and now they don't play a major role here? You may be absolutely right, but I maintain that you have not explained this clearly at all. I have understood your objection in the other comments now though.